# How to open Excel with a certain number style?

Tags: microsoft-excel, c#

how to open Excel,

and that the cell's styling will be Number with no numbers after the dot (.)

for example: the number 1234567890 will show 1234567890 not 1.23E+09

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

If the number format of the cells are correctly set already, you can do this using the AutoFit command.

```
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
usedRange.Columns.AutoFit();
```

Have a look here

[How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)

Comment: thank's for the help, but it do nothing

Answer (score 0):

you can read excel file like an access database with OleDB. then you can fill data into DataTable and work with it.